# Удалить пустые строки и столбцы

Tags: массивы, php

Есть двумерный массив данных в PHP. Мне нужно удалить из него пустые строки и пустые столбцы. Первый столбец может содержать строковое значение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, удобный способ реализации этой задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой вариант:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $items) {
    if (count(array_filter($items, 'strlen'))) {
        $result[$key] = $items;
    }
}
```

Для таких же любителей `array_walk()` как я (PHP >= 5.3.0):

```
$result = array();
array_walk($array, function($items, $key) use (&$result) {
    if (count(array_filter($items, 'strlen'))) {
        $result[$key] = $items;
    }
});
```

Для коллекции (PHP >= 5.4.0):

```
$result = new CallbackFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), function($row) {
    return count(array_filter($row, 'strlen')) > 0;
});
```

Если нули надо считать за пустые значения, то можно убрать второй параметр из `array_filter()`

Comment: Решение хорошее, но только чистит строки.

Comment: Прислушайтесь к совету @VlaD и повторно примените к транспонированному массиву.

Answer (score 3):

Проходитесь по всему массиву - сначала по строкам. Проверяете столбцы в строке, удаляете пустые. Если они все пустые - удаляете строку. Не вижу, в чем тут проблема.

```
$array = array(
    'first'=>array('10', '20', '30', '40'),
    'first1'=>array('10', '', '30', '40'),
    'first2'=>array('10', '20', '', '40'),
    'first3'=>array('10', '20', '30', '40'),
    'first4'=>array('10', '20', '30', '40'),
    'first5'=>array('', '', '', ''),
    'first6'=>array('10', '20', '30', '40'),
);

foreach($array as $ArrKey => $ArrList) {
    $delete = true;

    foreach($ArrList as $ArrKeyVals => $ArrVals) {
        if(empty($ArrVals)) {
            unset($array[$ArrKey][$ArrKeyVals]);
            continue;
        }
        $delete = false;
    }

    if($delete) {
        unset($array[$ArrKey]);
    }
}

/* $new_arr = array_map(function($data) {
    $data = array_filter($data, function($val) {
        if(!empty($val)) {
            return $val;
        }
    });

    if(count($data) > 0) {
        return $data;
    }
}, $array); */

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Проблемы нет. Просто ищу красивый способ это сделать.

Comment: Для строк можно применить array_filter, а со столбцами уже сложнее

Comment: @alekseidolganov зачем всё усложнять? обновил пост

Comment: Я не совсем понял ваш код, но мне кажется, что вы удаляете _все_ пустые элементы, а ТС хочет лишь те, для которых _весь столбец_ пустой.

Comment: @VladD цитата: "Мне нужно удалить пустые строки и пустые столбцы."

Comment: @lampa: Возможно, мы понимаем по-разному. Я понял эту цитату так: в матрице

    '10' '20' '30' '40' '' '60'
    '10'  ''  '30' '40' '' '60'
    '10' '20'  ''  '40' '' '60'
    '10' '20' '30' '40' '' '60'
     ''   ''   ''   ''  ''  ''
    '10' '20' '30' '40' '' '60'

надо удалить лишь предпоследний столбец и предпоследнюю строку, чтобы в результате получилось

    '10' '20' '30' '40' '60'
    '10'  ''  '30' '40' '60'
    '10' '20'  ''  '40' '60'
    '10' '20' '30' '40' '60'
    '10' '20' '30' '40' '60'

А у вас, кажется, получится не так.

Comment: @VladD аа, вы это имели ввиду. Может быть и так автору нужно. Хотелось бы услышать комментарий от @alekseidolganov

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо!
Сделал следующее решение:

```
$grid = array(
    array(1,0,0,0,0,0),
    array(0,1,0,0,0,0),
    array(0,0,0,0,0,0),
    array(1,0,1,0,1,1),
    array(1,0,0,0,1,0),
    array(1,0,1,0,0,1),
);
foreach($grid as $r1){
    foreach($r1 as $r) {
        print $r . ' ';
    }
    print '<br/>';
}
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
  $g = array();
  foreach($grid as $key => $row) {
    if(count(array_filter($row, function($c){return !empty($c);}))) {
      $g[$key] = $row;
    }
  }
  array_unshift($g, null);
  $grid = call_user_func_array('array_map', $g);
}
print '<br/>';
foreach($grid as $r1){
    foreach($r1 as $r) {
        print $r . ' ';
    }
    print '<br/>';
}
```